# Why regex do not get all matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex link is https://regex101.com/r/xAQoU0/4. There it finds two matches.

```js
const regex = /\$\$\[([(a-z-A-Z.)]*)]/;
const str = "<p>I have $$[worksAmount] works and $$[reviewsAmount] reviews</p>";
const match = regex.exec(str);
console.log(match)
```

But, when I run this snippet it logs in console only first match. So how to get all matches?

Comment: You have to set the _global_ flag `const regex = /\$\$\[([(a-z-A-Z.)]*)]/g;` This is what you're really doing https://regex101.com/r/CM5DYW/1. Also, exec returns an array in a different format than what you think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const regex = /\$\$\[([(a-z-A-Z.)]*)]/g;
const str = "<p>I have $$[worksAmount] works and $$[reviewsAmount] reviews</p>";
const match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match)
```

Comment: Thanks can you please accept my answer.